# How to Print Game Information onto *.txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x, text

I have made a Game which is like and RPG stat creator. However as part of the assignment, you have to print the stat onto a *.txt file.

I have got this far by using this website:

http://www.afterhoursprogramming.com/tutorial/Python/Writing-to-Files/

And the Code is:

```
   f = open("test.txt","a") #opens file with name of "test.txt"
   f.write("The Name of the Character is" ,name,)
   [Leave Line]
   [Leave Line]
   f.write("Class")
   [Leave Line]
   f.write("Strength /100:" ,strength,)
   [Leave Line]
   f.write("Magic /100:" ,magic,)
   [Leave Line]
   f.write("Dexterity /100: ,dexterity, ")
   [Leave Line]
   f.write("Extra Ability is...." ,extraability,)
   f.close()
```

But I don't know how to leave a line after each statistic. The end result should look like this:

[image]

The ,'something', are just variables I have made.

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: add a '\n' to each line and an additional for each blank line you want

Comment: You can write in document a blank line. Look for character like String.format("%n")

Comment: How would you change the test in test.txt into a variable?

Answer (score 0):

The same tutorial shows what the issue is -- you are missing a "\n" at the end of the string you write to the file.  For blank lines, write just "\n".

To include variables as part of the output string, you have a number of options -- there's a good example [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format)

Comment: How would you change the test in test.txt into a variable?

Answer (score 0):

As others already stated, your real problem here is the missing "\n". That said, I think a better solution than adding a "\n" for each line by yourself is writing what you want inside a list and then using a `str.join`:

```
content = [
    "The Name of the Character is" + name + "\n", # As first line has an extra blank line, this will be the only one with the explicit "\n"
    "Strength /100:" + strength,
    ...
]

base_name = "Frodo"
with open(base_name + ".txt","a") as f:
    f.write("\n".join(content)) # Maybe "\n\n" since you want a blank line between each attribute.
```

That should do the trick!

Comment: How would you change the test in test.txt into a variable?

Comment: I changed the example to show you how to change the ``test`` into the name of you character.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this all in one file write as follows:

```
with open("test.txt", "a") as f:   #opens file with name of "test.txt"

    dPlayer = {
        "name" : "Bob",
        "class" : "Wizard",
        "strength" : 50,
        "magic" : 30,
        "dexterity" : 85, 
        "extraability" : "speed"}

    output = """The Name of the Character is {name}


Class: {class}

Strength: {strength}/100

Magic: {magic}/100

Dexterity: {dexterity}/100

Extra Ability is....{extraability}
"""

    f.write(output.format(**dPlayer))
```

This would give you an output file looking like:

```
The Name of the Character is Bob


Class: Wizard

Strength: 50/100

Magic: 30/100

Dexterity: 85/100

Extra Ability is....speed
```

I have stored the player's details into a single dictionary and the keys can be used as placeholders in the string. By using a multiline string with triple quotes, it makes it quite easy to format the output exactly as you need it.

Also by using a `with` statement, the file is automatically closed afterwards.

If you would rather not use a dictionary (or the newer formatting method), you could use the following, but extra care is then needed to make sure all of the arguments match the order of the string.

```
with open("test.txt", "a") as f:   #opens file with name of "test.txt"
    name = "Bob"
    player_class = "Wizard"
    strength =  50
    magic = 30
    dexterity = 85
    extraability = "speed"

    player = (name, player_class, strength, magic,  dexterity, extraability)
    output = """The Name of the Character is %s


Class: %s

Strength: %d/100

Magic: %d/100

Dexterity: %d/100

Extra Ability is....%s
""" % player

    f.write(output)
```

Tested using Python 2.7